# Tensor flow object detection - detect the first detected object only

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection, tensor, detection

im working on one project in which I need to detect only one person at a time. I'm using tensor flow lite object detection. In that I customised to detect only person. Furthermore I need to detect only one person who is first detected on a frame and track that person only. Please help guys

I need a help regarding the above question. Just an idea to do that with syntax or example. Thank you

Comment: Do you have any code? What is the specific problem you're facing?

Comment: Currently I'm working with default tensor flow lite model object detection code. In which I modified for detect only a person. Now I need to detect only one person who is detected first.

Answer (score 0):

To detect only one person at a time and track that person across multiple frames, you can use a combination of object detection and object tracking techniques. Here's a high-level overview of the steps involved:

Use Tensorflow Lite Object Detection to detect people in the current frame.
If there are no people detected in the current frame, skip to step 1 with the next frame.

If there are multiple people detected in the current frame, choose the person closest to the person detected in the previous frame as the person to track.

If this is the first frame, choose the person closest to the center of the frame as the person to track.

Use an object tracking algorithm (such as Kalman filter or centroid tracking) to track the chosen person across multiple frames.

Repeat steps 1-5 for each frame.

Here's an example implementation using OpenCV and the Centroid Tracking algorithm:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Initialize object detection model (replace with your own model)
detection_model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('person_detection_model.pb')

# Initialize object tracking algorithm (Centroid Tracking)
class CentroidTracker:
    def __init__(self, max_disappeared=5):
        self.next_object_id = 0
        self.objects = {}
        self.disappeared = {}
        self.max_disappeared = max_disappeared
    
    def register(self, centroid):
        self.objects[self.next_object_id] = centroid
        self.disappeared[self.next_object_id] = 0
        self.next_object_id += 1
    
    def deregister(self, object_id):
        del self.objects[object_id]
        del self.disappeared[object_id]
    
    def update(self, bounding_boxes):
        if len(bounding_boxes) == 0:
            for object_id in list(self.disappeared.keys()):
                self.disappeared[object_id] += 1
                if self.disappeared[object_id] > self.max_disappeared:
                    self.deregister(object_id)
            return self.objects
        
        input_centroids = np.zeros((len(bounding_boxes), 2), dtype="int")
        
        for i, box in enumerate(bounding_boxes):
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = box
            cx = int((x1 + x2) / 2.0)
            cy = int((y1 + y2) / 2.0)
            input_centroids[i] = (cx, cy)
        
        if len(self.objects) == 0:
            for i in range(len(input_centroids)):
                self.register(input_centroids[i])
        else:
            object_ids = list(self.objects.keys())
            object_centroids = list(self.objects.values())
            
            distances = cv2.distanceTransform(np.ones((len(object_centroids), len(input_centroids))), distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2, maskSize=0)
            distances = distances * distances
            
            row_idx, col_idx = linear_sum_assignment(distances)
            
            used_rows = set()
            used_cols = set()
            
            for (row, col) in zip(row_idx, col_idx):
                if row in used_rows or col in used_cols:
                    continue
                
                object_id = object_ids[row]
                self.objects[object_id] = input_centroids[col]
                self.disappeared[object_id] = 0
                
                used_rows.add(row)
                used_cols.add(col)
            
            unused_rows = set(range(len(object_centroids))) - used_rows
            unused_cols = set(range(len(input_centroids))) - used_cols
            
            for row in unused_rows:
                object_id = object_ids[row]
                self.disappeared[object_id]
```